# sharepoint 2013 button onclick event gets removed after page save

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, html

I am trying to call a Javascript function through a button I posted on my sharepoint page like so

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Button</button>
```

But after I save the page and view the source again the code gets changed to this

```
<button type="button">Button</button>​​​
```

It totally removes the onClick event. Why is this? How can I fix it?

I have tried in the html editor, embedded code editor, and even tried to change it to input type=button all result in same behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The embedded source editor will strip the onclick event.

You will need to use a Content editor webpart or an HTML Form webpart.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/960cbc6f-ec7f-4641-88bd-0be3daa4668e/web-page-editor-not-accepting-onclick-attribute-in-button-tag?forum=appsforoffice

Comment: Hey yes this worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I tested as your description, and could reproduce this issue.

To avoid this issue, I suggest you Content Editor web part or Script Editor Web part.
[image]